# What is not_found in this geocouch error?

Tags: couchdb, couchbase, geo

I'm a bit new to geocouch, and have basically no experience with erlang, currently I am getting what I think might be an index corruption that leads to badmatch errors, but I'm not entirely sure. This response is returned after the server has been running for a while, and seems to increase in frequency over time. If I cleanup the spatial indexes, the error goes away for a few hours.

We are currently running couchbase-server-community_x86_64_1.1.deb and couchbase server says its version 1.0.2 in futon.

The query we are sending looks something like this:

```
'_design/blah/_spatial/customView?43.07960959232345743,-88.20843166111015421,43.08021240619384429,-88.20760633888984614'
```

where customView looks like this:

```
"customView": "function(doc) {if (doc.type && doc.type == \"Custom\") {emit({type: \"Point\", coordinates: [doc.loc[0], doc.loc[1]]}, doc);}};"
```

and the Custom doc type has this kind entry:

```
"loc": [
       42.873055,
       -73.767514
   ],
```

the response we get is this

```
ServerError: (500, ("{{badmatch,not_found},\n [{vtree,'-add_remove/5-fun-0-',3},\n  {lists,foldl,3},\n  {vtree,add_remove,5},\n  {couch_spatial_updater,'-write_changes/4-fun-2-',5},\n  {lists,zipwith,3},\n  {couch_spatial_updater,write_changes,4},\n  {couch_spatial_updater,update,2}]}", '{gen_server,call,[<0.12711.178>,{request_group,241518},infinity]}'))
```

so the issue is I understand this is a callstack, but I'm not entirely sure whats going on and was hoping someone could assist by providing some clues/context on what kind of error this is, ie. is this actually a corrupt index? or is this a known bug in the version of geocouch I'm using? or even what kind of actions can cause a not_found error? etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your query URL looks wrong, it's missing the "bbox=", but that's probably not the issue.

You are using a very old version of GeoCouch, it's actually a version using an now unsupported product of Couchbase. I suggest that you upgrade to a recent version of [Apache CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) together with a recent version of [GeoCouch](https://github.com/couchbase/geocouch/).

Let me know if you still see the same error.